# how to combine two regex with if else using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Problem:
Hi all, I have this sample dataframe which has institution names I need to extract:

```
mydf<- data.frame(ID=c('1', '2', '3'), Institution=c('Univ of Space, TX, US', '[Bloggs, J., Smith, T.] Univ of Time, CA, US', '[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US' ))
```

I need to extract the institution names only, such that it would appear like this:

```
1 Univ of Space
2 Univ of Time
3 College of the World
```

I don't care about any of the other characters in the institution string, only everything until the first comma. The issue is I have some instances where the institution name will be preceded by a bracket and sometimes on its own (as in the case of the first row).

I've written the following to extract these two instances separately:

```
ex_inst<- str_extract_all(mydf$Institution,"(?<=])(.+?)(?=,)", simplify = TRUE)
ex_inst2<- str_extract_all(mydf$Institution,"^(.+?)(?=,)", simplify = TRUE)
```

I'm struggling to combine them together. I have looked into the alternation, and tried this

```
ex_inst3<- str_extract_all(mydf$Institution,"^(.+?)(?=,)|(?<=])(.+?)(?=,)", simplify = TRUE)
```

But I'm not experienced with regex and am confused by what it's outputting:

```
[1,] "Univ of Space" ""                     
[2,] "[Bloggs"       " Univ of Time"        
[3,] "[Windz"        " College of the World"
```

What's the best way to combine this with stringr, can I use some sort of if else statement? 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` to capture the characters that are not a `,` while removing if there are any characters within square brackets including the brackets

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(mydf$Institution,"^(\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*)?([^,]+),.*", "\\2")
#[1] "Univ of Space"        "Univ of Time"         "College of the World"
```

---

Or using the same pattern with `sub`

```
sub("^(\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*)?([^,]+),.*", "\\2", mydf$Institution)
#[1] "Univ of Space"        "Univ of Time"         "College of the World"
```

#### Update

If we have multiple entries, one option it to split into components and then use the same code as above

```
v1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(mydf$Institution), ";\\s(?=\\[)", perl = TRUE))
sub("^(\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*)?([^,]+),.*", "\\2", v1)
#[1] "Univ of Space"        "Univ of Time"         
#[3] "College of the World" "College of the World" "Space Institute"
```

---

If we need to append as new column

```
lst1 <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(mydf$Institution), 
      ";\\s(?=\\[)", perl = TRUE), mydf$ID)
mydf2 <- stack(lst1)
mydf2$values <- sub("^(\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*)?([^,]+),.*", "\\2", stack(lst1)$values)
out1 <- aggregate(values ~ ., merge(mydf, mydf2, by.x = "ID", by.y = "ind"),
      FUN = paste, collapse = '; ')
out1[order(as.numeric(out1$ID)),]
#  ID                                                                                      Institution                                values
#4  1                                                                            Univ of Space, TX, US                         Univ of Space
#1  2                                                     [Bloggs, J., Smith, T.] Univ of Time, CA, US                          Univ of Time
#2  3                                                [Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US                  College of the World
#3  4 [Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US; [Bon, D.; Wilson, M.] Space Institute, TX, US College of the World; Space Institute
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), Institution = c("Univ of Space, TX, US", 
"[Bloggs, J., Smith, T.] Univ of Time, CA, US", "[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US", 
"[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US; [Bon, D.; Wilson, M.] Space Institute, TX, US"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

NOTE: Updated data from comments

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to do this if there were additional Institutions in the same string as well, such as ```[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US; [Bon, D.; Wilson, M.] Space Institute, TX, US``` Is there a way to pull out both 'College of the World' and 'Space Institute'

Comment: @vuvuzelling  Try `v1 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(mydf$Institution), ";\\s(?=\\[)", perl = TRUE));sub("^(\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*)?([^,]+),.*", "\\2", v1)#
[1] "Univ of Space"        "Univ of Time"         "College of the World" "College of the World" "Space Institute"`

Comment: this works perfectly but I'm confused as to how to get it back into a data frame with the components matching their respective IDs?

Comment: @vuvuzelling  Updated the post

Comment: thanks @akrun, works well. I'll mark yours as the answer as I like that there's a more complex regex for me to learn from in sub()

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `str_remove` and `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>%
    mutate(Institution = str_remove(Institution, "\\[.+\\]")) %>%
    separate(Institution, c("Institution", "State", "Country"), sep = ", ")
#  ID           Institution State Country
#1  1         Univ of Space    TX      US
#2  2          Univ of Time    CA      US
#3  3  College of the World    CA      US
```

You can remove the `State` and `Country` columns with `select(-State, -Country)`.

Or alternatively drop extra columns during `separate`

```
mydf %>%
    mutate(Institution = str_remove(Institution, "\\[.+\\]")) %>%
    separate(Institution, "Institution", sep = ", ", extra = "drop")
#  ID           Institution
#1  1         Univ of Space
#2  2          Univ of Time
#3  3  College of the World
```

---

### Update

In response to your comment, this seems to become a bit more complex.

For your revised sample data

```
mydf<- data.frame(
    ID=c('1', '2', '3', '4'),
    Institution=c('Univ of Space, TX, US', '[Bloggs, J., Smith, T.] Univ of Time, CA, US', '[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US', '[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US; [Bon, D., Wilson, M.] Space Institute, TX, US'))
```

we can do

```
mydf %>%
    mutate(Institution = map(
        str_split(Institution, "; "),
        ~trimws(str_remove(.x, "\\[.+\\]")))) %>%
    unnest(Institution) %>%
    separate(Institution, "Institution", sep = ", ", extra = "drop") %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(col = sprintf("Insitution%i", 1:n())) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = Institution)
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   ID [4]
#  ID    Insitution1          Insitution2
#  <fct> <chr>                <chr>
#1 1     Univ of Space        NA
#2 2     Univ of Time         NA
#3 3     College of the World NA
#4 4     College of the World Space Institute
```

Comment: I really like this alternative method and it works well for the example! I was using the str_extract because I may come across multiple institutions in the same string, so it would extract all it finds. Using mutate though it would only extract the first instance and then create the Institution column with that one instance, but how could I get around a problem where I may have a string like ```[Windz, P., Lol, D.] College of the World, CA, US; [Bon, D.; Wilson, M.] Space Institute, TX, US``` and I need to be left with both College of the World and Space Institute in two separate columns?

Comment: @vuvuzelling This is getting a bit more complex, I've made an edit to show an option. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to do this with one `sub` only however, here is one with two `sub` in base R

```
sub('(.*?),.*', '\\1', sub('\\[.*\\]', "", mydf$Institution))
#[1] "Univ of Space"         " Univ of Time"         " College of the World"
```

where the inner one is to remove everything inside the square brackets and the outer one is to capture until the first comma.

---

An alternative with `str_match`

```
stringr::str_match(mydf$Institution, "(\\[.*\\]\\s)?(.*?),")[, 3]
#[1] "Univ of Space"        "Univ of Time"         "College of the World"
```